# Feasibility of aromatic nucleophilic substitution of NO group by SH- nucleophile

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

(My approach)
In the first step, NO+ electrophile is generated which is substituted at the p position of the alkylated phenol. In the second step, HS- acts as a nucleophile and substitutes at p position with NO- as leaving group. However im doubtful about the feasibility of this reaction and NO- being a good leaving group. Also, the +M effect of -OH group lowers the possibility of nucleophilic substitution at para position. The only driving force for this reaction imo is HS- being a strong nucleophile but in that case, is it possible for it to substitute the OH group instead of NO??[image]

Comment: 1. The phenol will protonate the HS-   2. You need a significantly electron-withdrawing group p to the -NO for the displacement to work.